# How can I change the css styles of a modal dialog box made with jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am pretty confused as to why my CSS styles will not work for a dialog modal which I added to my site using jQuery UI (even when I try and utilize '!important'). I am thinking that the jQuery or UI CSS styles are already preset in one of the CDN links, and I can't seem to override them. Problem is that the pop-up modal (which I plan to be a login/registration modal [Php and MySQL]) clashes with the CSS style of my site. I am simply trying to give the modal a white background while making the rest of the site 'foggy' or 'blurry' until the client either click outside the modal or presses the close dialog 'X' icon.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Hebrews 13:3 Prison Ministry</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-jLKHWM3JRmfMU0A5x5AkjWkw/EYfGUAGagvnfryNV3F9VqM98XiIH7VBGVoxVSc7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;1,100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
          },
          hide: {
            effect: "fold",
            duration: 1000
          }
        });
     
        $( "#opener" ).on( "click", function() {
          $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
        
        
      } );
      </script>
         
    
</head>

<body>

<!------ SECTION 1: HOME -- Header Class ------>
<a id="header"></a>
<section class="header">
    <nav>
        <a href="index.php"><img src="hb13/logo.png" /></a>
        
        <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
        
                <div class="search-login">
                    
                    <div class="search">
                        <form action="#" method="POST">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search this site" name="search" >
                            <input type="submit" value="Search" for="search" class="submit"> 
                        
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    
                    <!------ Opens Sign in/up Modal ------>
                    
                    <div class="login">
                        <a href="#" id="opener">Login | Register</a>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
                      <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the &apos;x&apos; icon.</p>
                    </div>

                </div>  
                    
                    
                <ul>
                <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#charity">CHARITY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#updates">UPDATES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>   
            <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
            
            
            
        </div>
        <div class="text-box">
            <h1>Hebrews 13:3</h1> 
            <h2>Prison Ministry</h2>
            <p>"Remember those in prison, as if you were there yourself. <br>Remember also those being mistreated, as if you felt their pain in your own bodies." <br><br>- Hebrews 13:3 NLT -</p>
            <a href="" class="hero-btn">Click Here to Veiw More</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>
<hr>
  
<!-- SECTION 2:  -->
<a id="about"></a>
<section class="about">
    <h1>About the Ministry</h1>
    <p>The Book of Hebrews in chapter 13 verse 3 speaks of remembering those in prison as if you were there yourself.<br> The founder of this ministry was in prison. That is where he found Christ, and that is where he saw the desparate need for Christ in the lives of those in captivity.<br> Captivity is a double edged sword, since it is possible to be a captive to no fault of your own, or to make yourself a captive. The thing is that- whether innocent or guilty- ALL people need Christ.<br><br> It is easy to to think of God as a mere crutch that get us through difficult times. It is easy for us, when things are going relativley well, to forget the need for a Source of Power.<br>  </p>
    
    <div class="row">
        
        <div class="about-col">
            <h3>Text</h3>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="about-col">
            <h3>Text</h3>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="about-col">
            <h3>Text</h3>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    
    
    </div>
</section>

<a href="#header" class="align-right">Back to Top</a>
<hr>
  
<!-- SECTION: SERVICES -->
<a id="services"></a>
<section class="services">
    <h1>Services</h1>
    <p>text</p>
    
    <div class="row">
        
        <div class="services-col">
            <img src="hb13/bible_image(5).jpg"/>
            <div class="layer">
                <h3>Prayer Requests and Tools</h3>
            
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="services-col">
            <img src="hb13/bible_image(4).jpg"/>
            <div class="layer">
                <h3>Bible Studies and Bibles</h3>
            
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="services-col">
            <img src="hb13/bible_image(2).jpg"/>
            <div class="layer">
                <h3>Other Services</h3>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    
    
    </div>
</section>

<a href="#header" class="align-right">Back to Top</a>
<hr>  
  
<!-- your content here... -->
<a id="charity"></a> 
<section class="charity">
    <h1>Charity</h1>
    <p>text</p>
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="charity-col">
            <img src="hb13/charity(1).jpg" class="resize">
            <h3>IMG</h3>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="charity-col">
            <img src="hb13/charity(2).jpg" class="resize">
            <h3>IMG</h3>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="charity-col">
            <img src="hb13/charity.jpg" class="resize">
            <h3>IMG</h3>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    
    </div>
</section>

<a href="#header" class="align-right">Back to Top</a>
<hr>  

<!-- your content here... -->
<a id="updates"></a>
<section class="updates">
    <h1>Updates</h1>
    <p>text</p>
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="updates-col">
            <img src="hb13/me_1.jpg">
            <div>
                <p>text</p>
                <h3>IMG</h3>
            
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="updates-col">
            <img src="hb13/me_3.jpg">
            <div>
                <p>text</p>
                <h3>IMG</h3>
                <!-- i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i -->
            </div>
        </div>
</section>

<a href="#header" class="align-right">Back to Top</a>
<hr>

<!-- your content here... -->
<a id="contact"></a>
<section class="contact">
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    <a href="#" class="hero-btn">Contact Us</a>
</section>
<a href="#header" class="align-right">Back to Top</a>
<hr>

<!-- your content here... -->

<section class="footer">
    <h4>Links</h4>
    <p>footer text</p>
    <div class="icons">
        <a href=""><img src="hb13/fb.png"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="hb13/twitter.png"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="hb13/youtube.png"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="hb13/in.png"></a>
    
    </div>
    <p>Made with Love by Magdi Kanaan</p>


</section>
        

  <script type="text/javascript">
        
        var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");
        
            function showMenu() {
                navLinks.style.right = "0";
            }
            function hideMenu() {
                navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
            }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS. I placed the dialog selector declarations at the very top so that it would be easier to find.

```
**#dialog {
    color: white !important;
    background: white !important;
}**

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    
}

hr {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.align-right {
    margin-left:90%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f44336;
}

.align-right:hover {
    color: blue;        
}

.header {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7), rgba(4,9,30,0.7)), url("hb13/bible_image(1).jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    padding: 2% 6%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

nav img {
    width: 350px;
}

.nav-links {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
}

.nav-links ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav-links ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.nav-links ul li::after {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #f44336;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-links ul li:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}

.text-box {
    width: 90%;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.search-login {
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
}

.search {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.login {
    float: left;
}
.login a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f44336;
} 

.login a:hover {
    color: blue;
}

.text-box h1 {
    font-size: 62px;
}

.text-box h2 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-style: italic;
}

.text-box p {
    margin: 10px 0 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #fff;
}

.hero-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 12px 34px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hero-btn:hover {
    border: 1px solid #f44336;
    background: #f44336;
    transition: 1s;
}
.submit {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.submit:hover {
    border: 1px solid #f44336;
    background: #f44336;
    transition: 1s;
}

nav .fa {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
    .text-box h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    }
    .nav-links ul li {
    display: block;
    }
    .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    background: #f44336;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    right: -200px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 1s;
    } 
    nav .fa {
        display: block;
        color: #fff;
        margin: 10px;
        font-size: 22px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .nav-links ul {
        padding: 30px;
    }
    
}

.about {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

p {
    color: #777;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.row {
    margin-top: 5%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.about-col {
    flex-basis: 31%;
    background: #ccc/*#fff3f3*/;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    padding: 20px 12px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 10px 0;
    /* color: #fff; */
}

.about-col:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

@media(max-width: 700px) {
    .row {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}

/* -------- SERVICES ------- */

.services {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.services-col {
    flex-basis: 32%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.services-col img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.layer {
    background: transparent; 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.layer:hover {
    background: rgba(226,0,0,0.7);
}

.layer h3 {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 26px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.layer:hover h3 {
    bottom: 49%;
    opacity: 1;
}

.charity {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.charity-col {
    flex-basis: 31%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    text-align: left;

}

.charity-col img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.resize {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
}

.charity-col p {
    padding: 0;
}

.charity-col h3 {
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}

.updates {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.updates-col {
    flex-basis:44%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    text-align: left;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
}

.updates-col img {
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.updates-col p {
    padding:0;
}

.updates-col h3 {
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}

@media(max-width: 700px){
    .updates-col img {
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 15px;
    } 
}

.contact {
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 80%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),url("hb13/contact.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 625px 330px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px 0;
}

.contact h1 {
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 40px; 
    padding: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
    .contact h1 {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
}


.footer {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 0;
    
}

.footer h4 {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.icons {
    margin: 0 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px 0;
}
```

Just to reiterate on what exactly I am trying to figure out, it is the following 2 items:

1.) Override CSS styles for the Modal Pop-up, because I assume the styles are set already in the jQuery of jQuery UI CDN links.

2.) Blur the rest of the site while the Modal is actually open.

Comment: https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#theming

Answer (score 0):

I ran you code in my system and css was applying on modal,
[image: As You can see here]

try clearing your browser cache,

Or here's code of exactly what you want

```js
// Quick & dirty toggle to demonstrate modal toggle behavior
$('.modal-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.modal').toggleClass('is-visible');
});
```

```css
/**
 * Box model adjustments
 * `border-box`... ALL THE THINGS - http://cbrac.co/RQrDL5
 */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/**
 * 1. Force a vertical scrollbar - http://cbrac.co/163MspB
 * NOTE: Use `text-rendering` with caution - http://cbrac.co/SJt8p1
 * NOTE: Avoid the webkit anti-aliasing trap - http://cbrac.co/TAdhbH
 * NOTE: IE for Windows Phone 8 ignores `-ms-text-size-adjust` if the
 *       viewport <meta> tag is used - http://cbrac.co/1cFrAvl
 */

html {
  font-size: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* 1 */
  min-height: 100%;
}

/**
 * 1. Inherits percentage declared on above <html> as base `font-size`
 * 2. Unitless `line-height`, which acts as multiple of base `font-size`
 */

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;   /* 1 */
  line-height: 1.5; /* 2 */
  color: #444;
}

/* Page wrapper */
.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 4em auto;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Icons */
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  fill: currentcolor;
}

/* Headings */
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #222;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: inherit;
  line-height: 1.333;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

/**
 * Modals ($modals)
 */

/* 1. Ensure this sits above everything when visible */
.modal {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000; /* 1 */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.modal.is-visible {
    visibility: visible;
}

.modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
}

.modal.is-visible .modal-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 6em;
  left: 50%;
  width: 32em;
  margin-left: -16em;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.35);
}

.modal-transition {
  transition: all 0.3s 0.12s;
  transform: translateY(-10%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal.is-visible .modal-transition {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-header,
.modal-content {
  padding: 1em;
}

.modal-header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.06);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

.modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #aaa;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
}

.modal-close:hover {
  color: #777;
}

.modal-heading {
  font-size: 1.125em;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.modal-content > *:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.modal-content > *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Simple jQuery Modal</title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg display="none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="768" height="800" viewBox="0 0 768 800"><defs><g id="icon-close"><path class="path1" d="M31.708 25.708c-0-0-0-0-0-0l-9.708-9.708 9.708-9.708c0-0 0-0 0-0 0.105-0.105 0.18-0.227 0.229-0.357 0.133-0.356 0.057-0.771-0.229-1.057l-4.586-4.586c-0.286-0.286-0.702-0.361-1.057-0.229-0.13 0.048-0.252 0.124-0.357 0.228 0 0-0 0-0 0l-9.708 9.708-9.708-9.708c-0-0-0-0-0-0-0.105-0.104-0.227-0.18-0.357-0.228-0.356-0.133-0.771-0.057-1.057 0.229l-4.586 4.586c-0.286 0.286-0.361 0.702-0.229 1.057 0.049 0.13 0.124 0.252 0.229 0.357 0 0 0 0 0 0l9.708 9.708-9.708 9.708c-0 0-0 0-0 0-0.104 0.105-0.18 0.227-0.229 0.357-0.133 0.355-0.057 0.771 0.229 1.057l4.586 4.586c0.286 0.286 0.702 0.361 1.057 0.229 0.13-0.049 0.252-0.124 0.357-0.229 0-0 0-0 0-0l9.708-9.708 9.708 9.708c0 0 0 0 0 0 0.105 0.105 0.227 0.18 0.357 0.229 0.356 0.133 0.771 0.057 1.057-0.229l4.586-4.586c0.286-0.286 0.362-0.702 0.229-1.057-0.049-0.13-0.124-0.252-0.229-0.357z"></path></g></defs></svg>
  
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Simple jQuery Modal</h1>
    <button class="modal-toggle">Show modal</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-overlay modal-toggle"></div>
    <div class="modal-wrapper modal-transition">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="modal-close modal-toggle"><svg class="icon-close icon" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-close"></use></svg></button>
        <h2 class="modal-heading">This is a modal</h2>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit eum delectus, libero, accusantium dolores inventore obcaecati placeat cum sapiente vel laboriosam similique totam id ducimus aperiam, ratione fuga blanditiis maiores.</p>
          <button class="modal-toggle">Update</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```